# Cant figure out how to stop columns and rows from shifting in TkInter GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, grid-layout

So, I am working on a final project for my Python class and am creating a GUI for a game using TkInter. I have a little 'sprite' if you will that moves across the GUI using button presses. I am trying to figure out how to stop the annoying re-sizing of the rows and columns as the 'sprite' moves around. I would also like to know how to detect if a cell is occupied or not. It would really be great if I could somehow see the grid lines of the grid, but I dont think that is possible so the next best thing would be knowing how to permanently set up the grids columns and rows and make them unchangeable. I'm sorry if I'm not being clear on what I want I just have dozens of ideas running around in my head.

here is my code so far

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.constants import *

master= Tk()
master.resizable(width=False, height=False)

#for erasing displayed text when not needed anymore
wordsShowing = 0


#for testing button function with map movement
#url for image is http://files.softicons.com/download/game-icons/minecraft-avatars-icons-by-stefan-kroeber/png/50x50/slime.png if you want to see exactly what im seeing
pic = PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\Bill\\Desktop\\Python\\Final\\slime.png")
image = Label(master, image=pic)
image.grid(row=0, column=3, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, padx=0, pady=0)


#button functions (im not sure which buttons we will actually be using but im trying to cover all our bases)
def left():
    while wordsShowing == 1:
        varLabel.grid_remove()
        wordsShowing = 0
    info = image.grid_info()
    move = info["column"]
    stay = info["row"]
    if move > 0:
        image.grid_remove()
        image.grid(row=stay, column=move-1, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, padx=0, pady=0)
    else:
        varLabel = Label(master, text='Sorry, you can not go that direction.')
        varLabel.grid(row=1, column=2, rowspan=4)
        wordsShowing = 1
    global wordsShowing
    global varLabel

def right():
    while wordsShowing == 1:
        varLabel.grid_remove()
        wordsShowing = 0
    info = image.grid_info()
    move = info["column"]
    stay = info["row"]
    if move < 4:
        image.grid_remove()
        image.grid(row=stay, column=move+1, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, padx=0, pady=0)
    else:
        varLabel = Label(master, text='Sorry, you can not go that direction.')
        varLabel.grid(row=1, column=2, rowspan=4)
        wordsShowing = 1
    global wordsShowing
    global varLabel


def down():
    while wordsShowing == 1:
        varLabel.grid_remove()
        wordsShowing = 0
    info = image.grid_info()
    move = info["row"]
    stay = info["column"]
    if move < 5:
        image.grid_remove()
        image.grid(row=move+1, column=stay, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, padx=0, pady=0)
    else:
        varLabel = Label(master, text='Sorry, you can not go that direction.')
        varLabel.grid(row=1, column=2, rowspan=4)
        wordsShowing = 1
    global wordsShowing
    global varLabel


def up():
    while wordsShowing == 1:
        varLabel.grid_remove()
    wordsShowing = 0
    info = image.grid_info()
    move = info["row"]
    stay = info["column"]
    if move > 0:
        image.grid_remove()
        image.grid(row=move-1, column=stay, columnspan=1, rowspan=1, padx=0, pady=0)
    else:
        varLabel = Label(master, text='Sorry, you can not go that direction.')
        varLabel.grid(row=1, column=2, rowspan=4)
        wordsShowing = 1
    global wordsShowing
    global varLabel


def submit():
    var = command.get()
    varLabel = Label(master, text=var)
    varLabel.grid(row=1, column=2, rowspan=4)
    wordsShowing = 1
    global wordsShowing
    global varLabel


#created widgets
label1 = Label(master, text="Enter a command:")
command = Entry(master, width=80)
leftButton = Button(master, text="<", command=left)
rightButton = Button(master, text=">", command=right)
downButton = Button(master, text="v", command=down)
upButton = Button(master, text="^", command=up)
submitButton = Button(master, text="SUBMIT", command=submit)

#display widgets
label1.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=E)
command.grid(row=5, column=2)
leftButton.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=E, padx=3)
rightButton.grid(row=2, column=3)
downButton.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=W)
upButton.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=W)
submitButton.grid(row=5, column=3, pady=5, padx=5)
```

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I assume you're using Tkinter on purpose?  I mean, you're making a game, you looked at Pygame first right?

Comment: Your code is kind of long and I don't think all of these code is relevant to your problem. Please see: [MCVE]. Also, to draw a grid, you might want to check [`canvas`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_line.html).[`create_line()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_line-method)

Comment: Also, have you checked [`grid_propagate()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_propagate-method)?

Comment: Unless it is inherently part of the game that buttons and sprites be intermixed, I would not mix them in the same frame.  If I did want them together, I would use a canvas and put the buttons on the canvas http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_window.html and move the sprite around the canvas.

Comment: i guess i should have done more research. I did not know about Pygame. *facepalm*

sorry for the long code....

i will look into grid_propagate()

i just want like a layout of rooms, and when they go to a different room the sprite moves to that room.

Answer (score 0):

A minimum size for each grid cell can be set with the function .minsize.  If you set a minimum size that's always larger than the widgets you put into each cell, the cells will not change size as you move things around.  See this manual page: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid-config.html.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a few issues with your code if you are working on Python 3.X.

- <strike>The first problem is that you are trying to use a `.png` file whereas the `PhotoImage` class only accepts `.gif`, `.pgm`, or `.ppm` files. You can read the doc at [PhotoImage Doc](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm).</strike>
- The next issue, a warning, is that you are setting variables as `global` at the end of your functions. The way python works is that if a variable is declared inside a function it is local, so what you normally do is tell it at the start of the function, ok this variable is global, and THEN proceed to modifying it. If not you can't be sure that the variable you are working on is the global one you want.
- For the grid resizing, your best option is to put the buttons inside a grid, inside the grid so that their size is independent of the size of cells in the main grid. And it is better to display things on a frame rather than directly on master. I would change your code to be something like (and replace `Label`s and `Frame`s from functions to construct on `master` to construct on `gridFrame`):

  ```
  WIDTH = 200
  HEIGHT = 200

  master= Tk()
  master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
  gridFrame = Frame(master, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
  gridFrame.grid()

  # Your function code goes here

  buttonGrid = Frame(gridFrame)
  buttonGrid.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky=N)
  # created widgets
  label1 = Label(gridFrame, text="Enter a command:")
  command = Entry(gridFrame, width=80)
  leftButton = Button(buttonGrid, text="<", command=left)
  rightButton = Button(buttonGrid, text=">", command=right)
  downButton = Button(buttonGrid, text="v", command=down)
  upButton = Button(buttonGrid, text="^", command=up)
  submitButton = Button(gridFrame, text="SUBMIT", command=submit)

  # display widgets
  label1.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=E)
  command.grid(row=5, column=2)
  leftButton.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)
  rightButton.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W)
  downButton.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=N)
  upButton.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=S)
  submitButton.grid(row=5, column=3, pady=5, padx=5)
  ```
- The bit about knowing where something is can be easily maintainted by simply having a matrix that is initially empty and when you place something at a certain row and column, change those indices of the matrix to `True` and then simply check the matrix at position `[i][j]` to see if it is occupied

Hope that helped.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that when you are positioning on the grid in tkinter, the programming index of starting at 0 is maintained, so if you want the image to not go beyong the `Enter command:` Label, you could set its index column to 0 rather than 1.

Comment: tk 8.6, included with 3.4 and 3.5 on Windows, displays .png.  The linked doc is, I believe, a decade old or so.

Comment: The constraint still exists, I tried it with python 3.5.

Comment: I am on a Windows environment, not 100% sure, but due to file formats it might just be an issue with Windows.

Comment: What constraint are you referring to?  I *have* used and displayed .png files with tk8.6.

Comment: .png one, when i try the code with a .png file, I get:
`self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)`
`_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "C:\Users\Miguel\OneDrive\Pictures\jumped.png": invalid argument`
which is the error assigned to incorrected file type in the PhotoImage class
and yes obviously it is possible to do it, with a different class or via PIL, but if you take PhotoImage(.....) and assign it a file directly, the constraint exists

Comment: my code works fine with the .png it displays and moves around and everything. dont you need a double backslash in order for python to recognize the backslash?

Comment: I use forward slash and it works fine.  Backslashes are problematical.

Comment: The official tcl/tk doc: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/photo.htm "At present, only PNG, GIF and PPM/PGM formats are supported,"

Comment: Then might you know why it may be causing problems on my pc? I have windows 10, py3.5, tk8.6 and yet png are not being accepted :/

Comment: Also, yes I use the double backslash, if not the error would have been something like  `\U string command not recognized`